# Insert mutiple unique rows into a table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am not familiar with SQL that much. I'm trying to insert multiple rows of data into a table that if there exist a row with with duplicate value in `BusinessFilterPhrase` column then just don't insert. I wrote a pseudocode of what I think it should be.

```
if (filterCategoryList != null)
{
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> filter in filterCategoryList)
   {
      cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblBusinessName (BusinessFilterPhrase,BusinessCategoryID)" +
                        "select @BusinessFilterPhrase,@BusinessCategoryID" +
                        "from tblBusinessName as t1" +
                        "where NOT EXISTS" +
                        "( select * from tblBusinessName as d1 where d1.BusinessFilterPhrase = @BusinessFilterPhrase) ";

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessFilterPhrase", filter.Key);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessCategoryID", filter.Value.ToString());

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks correct.  I would write it as:

```
insert into tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase, BusinessCategoryID)
    select @BusinessFilterPhrase, @BusinessCategoryID
    from tblBusinessName t1
    where NOT EXISTS (select 1
                      from tblBusinessName d1
                      where d1.BusinessFilterPhrase = @BusinessFilterPhrase
                     )
```

(The changes are only cosmetic.)

EDIT:

If performance is an issue, create an index on `BusinessFilterPhrase`:

```
create index idx_tblBusinessName_BusinessFilterPhrase on tblBusinessName(BusinessFilterPhrase);
```

You can make this a `unique` index, if you want the database to enforce the uniqueness of the column (it will generate an error when duplicate values would be inserted).

Comment: Is there another way that scale better as queries go up to like > 500 insert? examples? joins?